# db.close() resulting in "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to run a function to insert into a mongoose database and then close the connection afterwards. My code is as follows:

```
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('mongoose connection error: ', err);
});

db.once('open', function () {
  console.log('mongoose connected successfully');
})
  .then(() => { return seedMongo() })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('finished seeding database')
    db.close()
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log('error with seeding mongo database: ', err))
```

When I run it, it gives me the following error:

```
(node:14130) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 70)
```

When I don't use db.close(), it runs the function and all, but just doesn't close the connection, so I know that function works.

Answer (score 0):

[connection.close()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-close) returns `Promise`. You should either handle it with `.catch` or use `async` function.

Or simply add `return` so it can be caught in existing chain.

Comment: Where should I add  "return "  to? I tried ```return db.close() ``` and that didn't work

Comment: That would be correct though so please describe what "didn't work" means exactly. The same warning?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, yes it throws the same error.